# Google Play - Internal testing for new application

Tags: android, google-play-console

I'm trying to test a new application before publish it for the first time.
I created a Internal testing and upload aab file and it seems to be OK.

[image]

[image]

I press on the link below to test the app (on my andrid phone)
[image]

I have got this screen - when i press on the link, Google play App is opened and it is stuck there (show refresh indicator)

[image]

what i did wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think if it's a new app then wait until google approves it. The internal testing works immediately for apps that are already approved. So, it will take approx of 1-3 days. Once your application is approved for internal testing it will take less than 4 - 5 hours for next updates to publish (or may be immediately).

Comment: That is the correct answer. First uploads still need to go through a first validation which can take a few days. After that, it will be immediate.

Comment: 4 days and still "in review"

Comment: @tokenaizer They have mentioned clearly on Play Console that new apps can take upto 7 or more days for review. It depends on various factors. Some apps are approved in few hours but some take 7 days or more.